# jQuery: simply $() select on #id not working in context of RoR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have some very very basic jQuery, which is using the `$()` operator to find an element by its `#id`.

Here is the emulated functionality with the exact replica of the HTML that is in my DOM:

https://jsfiddle.net/ebbnormal/h4ccgajn/

However, in the context of the following HAML/JS it breaks, even though I know that 1) jQuery is loaded and working 2)that my .js file is included in my application.js manifest file 3) that my .js is included in the `<head>` of the page in which the `console.log` should be printing and isn't.

Here is my view:

```
.front-page-calculator
  .calc-text
    Estimate your program cost.
  .calc-form

    =form_tag(controller: "school_applications", action: "calculate_price", method: "get", class: "calc_form") do 
      =select_tag "start_date", options_for_select(['February 9, 2015', 'April 6, 2015', 'May 4, 2015', 'June 1, 2015', 'June 29, 2015', 'July 27, 2015', 'August 25, 2015', 'September 21, 2015', 'October 19, 2015', 'November 16, 2015', 'December 14, 2015' ])
      -@option_array = (2..52).each.map {|i| ["#{i} weeks", i]}
      -@option_array = @option_array.unshift(["1 week", 1])
      = select_tag(:duration,options_for_select(@option_array))
     = select_tag(:fls_center,options_for_select( FlsCenter.all.map{|p| [p.name, p.id]}))
      = select_tag "housing_type", "<option></option>".html_safe, include_blank:true
      = select_tag "program", "<option></option>".html_safe, include_blank:true
      =submit_tag "Calculate Price"
```

Here is my `.js` file (`welcome.js`)

```
function removeOptions(selectbox)
{
    var i;
    for(i=selectbox.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        selectbox.remove(i);
    }
}
//using the function:

jQuery(document).ready(function(){


 $(".calc-form form #fls_center").change(function(){
   console.log("we are in a changed calc form");
    var center_id = document.getElementById(".calc-form fls_center").value;
    var formdata = {center: center_id};
    $.ajax({
        url: "/application/get_programs_for_center",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        data: formdata,
         success: function(response){
          var options = $(".calc-form program");
           removeOptions(options);
          $.each(response.programs, function(i,item) {
             options.append($("<option />").val(response.programs[i].id).text(response.programs[i].name));
          });
        }
    });
     var center_id =     document.getElementById("school_application_fls_center").value;
    var formdata = {center: center_id};
    $.ajax({
         url: "/application/get_airports_for_center",
         type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
         data: formdata,
         success: function(response){
          var options = $("#school_application_arrival_airport");
          removeOptions(document.getElementById("school_application_arrival_airport"));
          $.each(response.airports, function(i,item) {
             options.append($("<option />").val(response.airports[i].id).text(response.airports[i].name));
          });
          options.append($("<option />").val('-1').text('None'));
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my `application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Here is the `<head>` of my generated view

```
<head>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/core.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widget.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/button.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/mouse.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/draggable.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/position.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/resizable.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/dialog.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/sortable.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/tabs.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/base.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/batch_actions.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/checkbox-toggler.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/dropdown-menu.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/flash.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/has_many.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/modal_dialog.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/per_page.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/popover.js?body=1"></script>     
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/table-checkbox-toggler.js?body=1">   </script>
 <script src="/assets/active_admin/ext/jquery-ui.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/ext/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/application.js?body=1"></script>
 <script src="/assets/active_admin.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application_payment.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/locations.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/school_application.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/welcome.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
</head>
```

in spite of all this, it am still not seeing my `console.log` statements.

N.B.

Because I was dubious if my jQuery context was set up correctly, I added the `$()` operator to a `.js` file which is correctly detecting the change of `<select>` tags. When I put:

```
 $(".calc-form form #fls_center").change(function(){
console.log("we are in a changed calc form");

 });
```

inside the `jQuery(document).ready(function(){})`
it still does not work, even though when I copy and paste
     $(".calc-form form #fls_center")

in my JS console in my chrome browsers, it successfully selects the `<select>` tag.

Comment: @LouisK precisely, which is why i am confused it isn't working inside my RoR app.

Comment: It is hard to debug "it breaks". What is the issue? Be specific. Based on what you posted I would imagine that the id "fls_center" does not exist, probably because your indentation is wrong. What is the generated html? Does is look like you expect?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ebbnormal/06bb55b7cbf8eb1f083f

Comment: @ptd Specifically, nothing happens,  namely, no error is reported in my JS console, neither is the change of the `<select>` with id `fls_center` detected by the `$('').change` operator. As I say in the N.B. of my post, replicating the `$()` verbatim in my JS console successfully selects the `<select>` which eliminates it being a indentation / DOM structure issue, but rather a JS one.

Comment: i.e. when I write `$(".calc-form form #fls_center")` in the JS console of chrome I get: `[<select>all the coveted options etc. </select>]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip out all your JavaScript leaving only

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
  $(".calc-form form #fls_center").change(function(){
    console.log("we are in a changed calc form");
  });
});
```

to make sure this is firing properly and then add back your js code piece by piece.

I think there are possibly a few errors in your code that is preventing this from working. For example, `var center_id = document.getElementById(".calc-form fls_center").value;` is invalid.